# Invariant theory over rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, invariant-theory

Apologies if this is a silly question, but I have had cause to briefly introduce myself to invariant theory. I have noticed that authors primarily work over (algebraically closed) fields. I was wondering if a generalisation to rings is actually an active field of research; if not, why not?

From a purely algebraic point of view, it seems an obvious next step. To ensure you still have a basis from which to build the ring of invariants you can simply restrict yourself to free modules over the base ring. On the other hand, perhaps there is an obvious geometric reason why this isn't the case

As I say, apologies if there is an obvious answer to this, I am very new to this area and still trying to get my bearings.

Comment: Seshadri, C. S.,
*Geometric reductivity over arbitrary base*,
Advances in Math., vol 26, 1977, no. 3, pp.  225--274.

Comment: Invariant theory over rings exists. Many algebraic arguments (e.g., Capelli identities, tableau-theoretic methods, standard monomial theory, as done e.g. by Rota, Procesi and Brini) work over rings or at least $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras. I have not seen a book treating this systematically, though.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thanks, I should have thought to look up Seshadri.

Comment: I may be showing my ignorance here, but isn't the geometric version of this Mumford's GIT?

Comment: For finite groups, algorithms for computing the invariant ring over a base ring such as the integers are given in G. Kemper, Using Extended Derksen Ideals in Computational Invariant Theory, J. Symbolic Comput. 72 (2016), 161-181.

Comment: Vincent Franjou and Wilberd van der Kallen ,
Power reductivity over an arbitrary base,
Documenta Mathematica, Extra Volume Suslin (2010) , pp. 171-195.

Comment: @GregorKemper and WilberdvanderKallen Many thanks for the papers. These were just what I was looking for.

Comment: One thing that comes up in the case of finite groups: if the ground ring is mixed characteristic, then invariant theory over it will usually need to contend with modular issues. There will usually not be a Reynolds operator, i.e. the invariant ring will not be a direct summand (unlike over fields in the nonmodular case).