# Algorithmic invariant theory of finite groups acting on finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras: reference request

Tags: reference-request, invariant-theory

Does there exist a book discussing algorithmic invariant theory for finite groups that does not assume that the algebras involved are defined over a field (e.g. base rings $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/n$ are allowed)? I could not find one though I can not claim a good knowledge of the literature.

Comment: a related thread https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279253/invariant-theory-over-rings

Comment: especially Gregor Kemper's comment- For finite groups, algorithms for computing the invariant ring over a base ring such as the integers are given in G. Kemper, Using Extended Derksen Ideals in Computational Invariant Theory, J. Symbolic Comput. 72 (2016), 161-181.

Comment: I am not aware of a book (and would very much like to know about it if it exists). If a method involves a Reynolds operator, it won't work over $\mathbb{Z}$, but some other methods do. E.g., the shelling method in Garsia and Stanton (1984), Group actions on Stanley-Reisner rings and invariants of permutation groups, *Advances in Mathematics* 51(2): 107-201 https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870884900057 for finding secondary invariants of a permutation group works (when a shelling exists, which, in fairness, is rare) over $\mathbb{Z}$.